# grunt.file.copy exclude empty folders

Tags: gruntjs, copy, directory

file.copy (actually grunt-config-copy but it uses grunt.file.copy underneath).  This is working fine for me but I'm excluding certain glob patterns.  This exclusion results in some empty folders, and the folders are still copied to new set.  Is there any way to exclude empty folders?
Thanks,
Raif

here is my grunt-task

```
copy: {            
        release: {
                expand: true,
                deleteEmptyFolders:true,
                cwd:'<%= srcFolder %>',
                src: ['**',
                      '!**/obj/**',
                      '!**/*.cs',
                      '!**/*.vb',
                      '!**/*.csproj',
                      '!**/*.csproj.*'
               ],
               dest: '<%= destFolder %>',
               filter: function(filepath) {
                 var val = !grunt.file.isDir(filepath) || require('fs').readdirSync(filepath).length > 0;
                 grunt.log.write(val);
                 return val
              }
            }              
    }
```

the log shows that there are some false values being returned but I still have several empty folders in my desFolder.

Comment: It's actually [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)

Comment: right, just getting blurry.

Comment: I've just realized that those folders are not empty.

Comment: @IlanFrumer I"m sorry I don't follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE

I made a [PR](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/pull/128) to grunt-contrib-copy but @shama came up with a better solution.

You can now handle this in **all grunt tasks** using filter:

```js
copy: {
  main: {
    src: 'lib/**/*',
    dest: 'dist/',
    filter: function(filepath) {
      return ! grunt.file.isDir(filepath) || require('fs').readdirSync(filepath).length > 0;
    },
  },
},
```

The problem with your case is that those folders are not empty just being excluded.

A good solution would be to use grunt-contrib-copy and then grunt-contrib-clean :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
      main: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'src',
        src: ['**', '!**/*.js'],
        dest: 'dist/'
      }
    },
    clean: {
      main: {
        src: ['*/**'],
        filter: function(fp) {
          return grunt.file.isDir(fp) && require('fs').readdirSync(fp).length === 0;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.registerTask('copyclean', ['copy:main', 'clean:main']);
};
```

Comment: I will take a look at this.  seems like it makes sense, but I've been pulled off to do something else.  I may have ? for you when I"m back on.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, a) that's awesome, thanks for super fast turn around.  b) how do I get this version of grunt-contrib-copy?  I'm currently have "~0.5.0" in my project.json file.  I presume since you just did this that I should update that version?

Comment: My PR was rejected because grunt has built-in support for filtering files and folders for all plugins. Just copy the updated snippet and you are good to go.

Comment: strangely this does not seem to work. I will update my ? with my grunt task.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I think what is happening with the first solution is that it is looking at the source file, not the destination.  The source has files, but what is copied is just the empty folder because those files are filtered out.  So the source has files and thus is copied but the dest does not and thus sucks.  Anyway, I had also come to your second solution, I'm using a package called grunt-cleanempty  which works, I was just hoping to do it al in one task.  Thanks again for your help.