# How can I skip a grunt task if a directory is empty

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using grunt-contrib's `concat` and `uglify` modules to process some javascript.  Currently if `src/js/` is empty, they will still create an (empty) concat'd file, along with the minified version and a source map.

I want to task to detect if the `src/js/` folder is empty before proceeding, and if it is, then the task should skip (not fail).  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Would you mind posting a copy of your `Gruntfile.js`? Have you tried doing everything through `uglify` only (also the concatenation), just for the sake of testing?

Comment: Related/duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001469/grunt-file-copy-exclude-empty-folders

Comment: The source is available here: https://github.com/jtfairbank/Milkshake

Comment: I'm specifically trying to solve the 2nd and 3rd TODOs in the Gruntfile.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution may not be the prettiest, but could give you an idea. You'll need to run something like `npm install --save-dev glob` first. This is based on part of the `Milkshake` project you mentioned.

```
grunt.registerTask('build_js', function(){
  // get first task's `src` config property and see
  // if any file matches the glob pattern
  if (grunt.config('concat').js.src.some(function(src){
    return require('glob').sync(src).length;
  })) {
    // if so, run the task chain
    grunt.task.run([
        'trimtrailingspaces:js'
      , 'concat:js'
      , 'uglify:yomama'
    ]);
  }
});
```

A gist for comparison: https://gist.github.com/kosmotaur/61bff2bc807b28a9fcfa

Comment: Thanks this ended up being just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

With this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-file-exists

You can check file existence. (I didn't try, but the source looks like supporting grunt expands. (*, ** ...)

For example like this::

```
grunt.initConfig({
  fileExists: {
    scripts: ['a.js', 'b.js']
  },
});

grunt.registerTask('conditionaltask', [
    'fileExists',
    'maintask',
]);
```

But maybe if the file doesn't exist it will fail with error instead of simple skip.
(I didn't test it.)

If this is a problem you can modify a bit the source of this plugin to run the related task if the file exists:

The config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  fileExists: {
    scripts: ['a.js', 'b.js'],
    options: {tasks: ['maintask']}
  },
});

grunt.registerTask('conditionaltask', [
    'fileExists',
]);
```

And you should add this:

```
grunt.task.run(options.tasks);
```

In this file:

https://github.com/alexeiskachykhin/grunt-file-exists/blob/master/tasks/fileExists.js

after this line:

```
grunt.log.ok();
```

Comment: Looks like it'll work, but I'd prefer a cleaner solution than using a patched version of grunt-file-exists.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is just a more up-to-date answer as the others are more than a year old, but you don't need a plugin for this; you can use `grunt.file.expand` to test if files matching a certain globbing pattern exist.

Update of @Kosmotaur's answer (path is just hard-code here though for simplicity):

```
grunt.registerTask('build_js', function(){
  // if any file matches the glob pattern
  if (grunt.file.expand("subdir/**/*.js").length) { /** new bit here **/ 
    // if so, run the task chain
    grunt.task.run([
        'trimtrailingspaces:js'
      , 'concat:js'
      , 'uglify:yomama'
    ]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Marc!

Could you provide a bit more context for your code?  Would I use that directly in a `src` string value or `files` array?

Or would I use it in the top part of the function like @Kosmotaur did?  If so, could you mimic his layout and provide a full example function?

Comment: Worked for me,Thanks!